# WCF: Cannot find certificate by common name but by serial number

Tags: .net, wcf, security, certificate

I am trying to load a certificate for securing my WCF service. It works quite well by using the serial number of the certificate. That means that the certificate is accessable for the IIS process and can be used.

But in the final solution I need to use the common name to find the certificate. That is where the problems appear. The certificate is not found. Every time I change from the serial number to the common name I get an InvalidOperationException which says that the certificate cannot be found by the search criteria.

```
<serviceCredentials>            
        <serviceCertificate findValue="‎CN=*.mycompany.net, O=MyCompany Inc, L=MyCity, S=Nordrhein-Westfalen, C=DE" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</serviceCredentials>
```

The only things I change compared to the serial number version are the findValue and the x509FindType. I checked that twice. So the common name should be correct.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience you have to essentially cut and paste from the cert's details into your search criteria. The search is very sensitive, even to spaces.

Comment: I checked that over and over again. There shouldn't be any typo in it. I even tried to type the string to prevent having invisible characters in it but with no impact.

Comment: how you got this fixed, I am facing same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set findValue to `*.mycompany.net`.

Please note that using DN as find value might be a problem when you add another certificate with same name to the store (after the first certificate expires). Then it will find two and will not know what certificate to use.

Even using serial number does not guarantee uniqueness of certificate because another CA might issue a certificate with the same serial number. Only a combination of DN of the issuer and serial number SHOULD be unique, but who in this world can quarantee that :)

The safe way is to use thumbprint. I know that even in SHA1 there might be collisions but the chance is very low. But using thumbprint is not very user/admin friendly as you don't know from first look what certificate is being used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually setting the find value to #.mycompany.net did not solve the problem. I tried to load the certificate out of the certificate store by using the following code which worked fine: `code`X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "CN=*.mycompany.net, O=MyCompany Inc, L=MyCity, S=Nordrhein-Westfalen, C=DE" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" storeLocation="LocalMachine", true);

Comment: Ok, my fault. Try to change X509FindType to `FindBySubjectName` and leave findValue as `*.mycompany.net`.

Comment: Hm, and is it working with serial number? I does not make any sense :)

Comment: That is exactly my problem :)

Comment: In the first comment you said that `#.mycompany.net` did not work. So did you try `#.mycompany.net` or `*.mycompany.net`?

Comment: Just a typo in the comment. I used *.mycompany.net.

Comment: Well actually thumbprint would have the same disadvantage as the serial number. Every time the certificate expires I will have to change the config. As that is not in my hands I want to keep that as easy as possible for our customer...

Comment: How many certificates did the test from first comment return? And how many does it return when you set last parameter to false?

Comment: Just one. Changing the param to false does not have any effect. It still finds one certificate.

Comment: Could you paste the DN as you see it in certificate details? I am nearly out of ideas. This definitely should work with DN, serial of thumbprint. I tried it countless times with dev certificate issued to localhost.

Comment: Well, that is what you see above. I just replaced the actual company name and city. Maybe it is a problem of escaping the characters. Is there any char that has to be escaped in the web.config so that it can be used?

Comment: My thought was if DN is not reversed.

Comment: What do you mean by "DN is not reversed"?

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly i.e. windows xp generated (or displayed? ) subject in reversed order compared to windows 7.

Comment: Just now I made a test of WCF service with certificate in local machine store. When I was testing findBySubjectName I found out that I could just put `mycompany.net` in findValue and it worked. I was using console application and I was admin so no permission problems could stop me.

Comment: Your certificate subject string can be either in Ansi or in Unicode. Either try with specific calls from CryptoAPI or try with both the type of strings to confirm which one is working.

Comment: I tried to create a WCF service, too. But compared to the one I previously created it does not get its config from a web.config. I created it with hard coded string. This way the certificate is found without problems.

Comment: That makes sense because you had no problems with finding the certificate from code. But is it all right for your customer if it would be in code? Then what about this: make a setting in appSettings and put DN of certificate there. Then initialize service from code, find certificate and bind it to the service behavior.

Comment: Well, I thought of this, too. That is gonna be my fallback :)